# Any potential problems with the density of a planet with a volume 8 times that of Earth but the same surface gravity as Earth?

Tags: planets, geophysics

Assuming that there is an Earth-like planet that has 8 times the volume, 2.83 times the radius, and has the same surface gravity as Earth, and has oceans; what are potential problems concerning the density of this planet if it isn't hollow that risk it being less Earth like either composition-wise or just in how hard or soft the surface is?

Comment: Average density would be like 0.35 of density of Earth, right? You may be interested in [biggest reasonable planet with Earth surface gravity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/96984/809) I asked for earlier.

Comment: When you say earthlike, can it be made out of something different?

Comment: Based on the answers to Molot's question, your planet will need to be almost entirely ammonia and/or water. You might have to rethink your planet, or make it out of handwavium (in other words, not worry about making it scientifically accurate).

Comment: Molot - Yeah, the density would only be 35% that of Earth. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have to take a look at your question. Robb Watts - Yeah, I'll have to rethink the size of the planet. PotatoLatte - The planet can be made of something different, but the qualifications for the planet I'm looking for are that it can support plant, animal and human life brought over from Earth and that it has oceans and very fertile soil (at least somewhere it does). But again, I'll have to rethink the size of my planet.

Comment: Since gravity is a function of mass, no. Saturn is much less dense than water, yet it's gravity is much more than Earth's because it has that much more mass.

Comment: My answer was wonky-off, but there are still issues.  Go read my answer to [Geology on low-density planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/122931/geology-on-low-density-planets/122940#122940).  You can't significantly compress a liquid metal core (needed for magnetospheres) and the larger surface area means other problems.

Comment: As Pojo-guy already pointed out, Gravity is directly proportional to Mass, the gravity might be the same if the size was 2.83 the radius so long as the density was a lot lower but as you've said but the mass would actually be the same

Comment: @BladeWraith **surface** gravity would be 0.9988 of Earth with the numbers OP provided. It would be increased by the increased mass, but decreased by the bigger distance from the center of mass.

Comment: @pojo-guy Saturns surface gravity is 10.44 m/s2 and effective surface gravity on equator  8.96 m/s2 - Quite similar to Earth surface gravity of 9.81 m/s2.

Comment: It is hard ot have oceans on a planet where the ground floats, On your planet the ground is less dense than water.

Comment: Ummm… the radius is 2.83 times that of Earth. The volume is 8 times that of Earth, so the radius must be 8^(1/3) which is 2 times that of Earth. Which one do you want?!

Answer (score 1):

To shed mass you would have to lose your iron/molten core and the protective magnetic field it creates to shield your atmosphere from solar winds. And without a molten core you wouldn't have enough volcanic activity to replenish your atmosphere.

As a solution you could have a core of metallic hydrogen (~%7 the density of iron). It would allow you to maintain your magnetosphere while achieving your desired volume and gravity without significantly changing the surface characteristics of the mantle.